# S3 getSignedUrl won't set the region correctly. Gets a 307 error when uploading files using the url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I just used the following code to get an S3 pre-signed URL:

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_S3_KEY,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_S3_SECRET,
  region: process.env.AWS_S3_REGION
});

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  region: process.env.AWS_S3_REGION,
  signatureVersion: 'v4'
});

export const s3Auth = (req, res) => {
  s3.getSignedUrl(
    'putObject',
    {
      Bucket: 'bucket',
      Key: 'mykey',
      ContentType: 'multipart/form-data',
      Expires: 60
    },
    (error, url) => {
      if (!error && url) {
        res.send({
          url
        });
      } else {
        res.status(500);
        res.send({ error: 'AWS error!' });
        throw error;
      }
    }
  );
};
```

As you can see I set my region in both AWS and AWS.S3 objects. But still, the URL returned by this function does not include the correct region. It returns `us-east-1` instead of `ap-southeast-1` which I set. The environment variables are coming correctly. I tested them. Any idea what's happening?

Sample url:

```
https://{BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com/{FOLDER}?Content-Type=multipart%2Fform-data&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential={KEY}%2F20171023%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request...
```

Comment: `ContentType: 'multipart/form-data'` would probably not be correct for a `PUT` request, but that seems unrelated.  You aren't logging the value of `process.env.AWS_S3_REGION` so it's not clear how you confirmed that it is correct at runtime.  Please able what your signed URL looks like, with as little redaction as possible.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Hi, I did console log the AWS_S3_REGION but removed the code when pasting it here to keep it clean. I did add a sample url I get.

Comment: In your env file what do you have set as the region? Without details to what framework you are using, it is possible that the env file has the wrong information or perhaps there is a config file that is setting the variable to default to us-east-1

Comment: @ZacharyWeixelbaum Thanks, I found my mistake. I console logged `process.env.AWS_S3_REGION` inside the function and it worked. But when the function initializes `process.env.AWS_S3_REGION` will be undefined because I only run `dotenv.config()` in app.js. I also need to run it in this file before everything.